# How to find the index of the closest valid value, given two boolean arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

Basically, I have a problem in which I have two arrays of length `L`: a data array (let's call it `D`), representing my actual data, and a validity array (called here `V`), with boolean values, saying which of these values are valid.

For instance, imagine I have:

```py
D = [10, 20, 40, 1000, 2000, -1000, 50, 20, 1000]
V = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

In this case, my `V` array indicates that values on indexes 3, 4, 5 and 8 are invalid.

For each of these indexes, I want to replace the corresponding data values `D[i]` with the data from the closest valid index.

So my index finding function (that only takes on the validity array) would give:
    `f(V) == [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7, 7]` (or
    `f(V) == [0, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]`, doesn't really matter)

In this case, I could correct my `D` array with:

```py
D[i] = D[f(V)]
```

And get:

```py
D == [10, 20, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 20, 20]
```

Is something like this implemented in Python? If not, how could I implement this easily?

Comment: There is nothing like that already implemented in Python — so you'll have to write your own.

Comment: why wouldn't 50 (index 6) be the closest to the "invalid" values 1000 (indices 3 and 8)?

Comment: I worded it wrong, sorry! I meant the data on the closest valid index (closest in terms of index, since it represents a time array)

Comment: ok, then it's even (much) simpler. Updated answer coming soon.

Comment: Yeah that's what I imagined :) thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Oh yeah I know, I am indeed using numpy arrays, I'll fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Pandas Series, you can do it in one line (after initialization):

```py
d = pd.Series(D)
v = pd.Series(V).astype(bool)

out = d[v].reindex(d.index, method='nearest')
```

Or, as a list:

```py
D2 = d[v].reindex(d.index, method='nearest').tolist()
```

The result on your data is:

```py
>>> D2
[10, 20, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20]
```

**Edit**: `numpy`-only:

Doing this using only `numpy` is a touch more complex. First, we use a cumulative sum with reset at zero to find the delta index, both forward and backward. Care has to be taken for cases where `v` starts and/or ends with `0`.

```py
def cumsum_reset0(v):
    v = v.copy()
    zero = v == 0
    c = np.cumsum(~zero)
    v[zero] = -np.diff(np.r_[0, c[zero]])
    return np.cumsum(v)

def closest_index(v):
    assert np.any(v), "no valid index found"
    n = len(v)
    a = cumsum_reset0(1 - v)
    b = cumsum_reset0((1 - v)[::-1])[::-1]
    i = np.arange(n)
    a[i - a < 0] = n
    b[i + b >= n] = n
    return np.where(a < b, i-a, i+b)
```

Example:

```py
>>> closest_index(np.array(V))
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])

>>> closest_index(np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7])

>>> closest_index(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]))
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

But:

```py
>>> closest_index(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
AssertionError: no valid index found
```

Comment: Do you think there's a quick way to implement this with only numpy?

Comment: Yes. It's a bit more complex but still relatively easy to do and fast. See "edit" at the end.

Comment: Yep, this one solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` and [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'D': D, 'V': V})
D2 = (df['D']
     .mask(df['V'].eq(0))
     .interpolate(method='nearest')
     .ffill(downcast='infer')
     .tolist()
     )
```

output: `[10, 20, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 20, 20]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using only built-in Python functions (i.e. no `numpy`, `pandas`, or anything else required). The `f()` function literally searches for the closest valid index in `D` given the index of an invalid data element.

```
D = [10, 20, 40, 1000, 2000, -1000, 50, 20, 1000]
V = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

def f(V):

    def index_of_closest(i, V):
        """Find valid index closest_index to index i based on V validity arrary."""
        closest_index = V.index(1)  # Init to index of first valid element.
        min_diff = abs(closest_index-i)  # Init to difference between indices.
        for index in range(len(V)):  # Search for an even closer index.
            if V[index]:  # Valid?
                index_diff = abs(index-i)
                if index_diff < min_diff:
                    closest_index = index
                    min_diff = index_diff
        return closest_index

    return [i if V[i] else index_of_closest(i, V) for i, d in enumerate(D)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = f(V)
    print(f'{D=}')  # -> D=[10, 20, 40, 1000, 2000, -1000, 50, 20, 1000]
    print(f'{r=}')  # -> r=[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7, 7]
    print()
    print('Updated D')
    D = [D[i] for i in f(V)]  # -> D=[10, 20, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 20, 20]
    print(f'{D=}')
```